# How many bunt home runs has there been in the history of MLB?

Tags: baseball, trivia, history, mlb, home-run

I'd like to know how many times a bunt resulted in a home run. The home runs can be out of the park (highly unlikely to have happened) or inside the park home runs cause by one or more errors. In addition, please provide the name of the hitter and the date of the event.

If this can't be searched for the entirety of MLB's history, go back as far as possible. I can edit the question to ask for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: Are you asking about a scored HR, or a situation where a bunting batter reached home after an error? I can't imagine a scored HR happening.

It could be demonstrated with physical assumptions that a bunted ball could not fly over the fence of a modern field.

Comment: @davidmneedham I once saw a bunt ball make it past the infield. There are a few videos of out of park home runs online (spoiler: they are all fake). All home run bunts I've been able to find are result of error(s) which yielded inside park homers. But just in case the impossible happens, let's leave out of park home runs in the question.

Comment: @davidmneedham I however edited the question to make it clearer. Thanks for your comment

Comment: This reminded me of a story that I can't find and I don't know if it really happened (maybe just my imagination!), but it was along these lines: a batter bunted, the ball rolled down the foul line and the fielders waited for it to roll foul.  They then spent time arguing with the umpire, trying to convince him that it should be ruled foul, all while the batter continued around the bases and scored.  A true bunt home run; it would be nice though if I could figure out where I got that story from.

Comment: A single followed by an error is not a home run, so the question is faulty on its face.

Comment: @Joe Is that the case just for the first base, or all bases? I just want to know the number times the bunter made it to the home plate, I could reword the question

Answer (score 4):

Regarding over-the-fence bunt home runs, the [minimum observed off-the-bat speed for a home run in 2016 is about 90 mph](http://www.hittrackeronline.com/). The [coefficient of restitution (COR) limit for MLB baseballs is 0.578](https://pubs.acs.org/cen/whatstuff/stuff/7713scit3.html). Assuming that a ball being bunted acts like the MLB's COR test, that implies a pitch speed of 156 mph (90 mph / 0.578) is required for a bunt home run.

An inside-the-park bunt home run is plausible, but I was unable to find any evidence that it has ever happened without it being the result of an error.

Answer (score 0):

Robert Dozier did it for the Twins leading off the first inning on [September 24, 2017](http://www.espn.com/mlb/playbyplay?gameId=370923106). But as above mentioned, the stats call it a single with a throwing error.

Comment: A single with a throwing error is not a home run.

Answer (score -2):

A bunt home run is impossible, because if there is slew of errors that allows the runner to run around the bases, it's considered a single(or out or whatever) with advancements due to errors.

Comment: please add reference for this.

Comment: What you're trying to describe is an inside the park home run as described in the question and its comments. Also your post doesn't answer the question